# Auto find and replace Google Sheet every time I run the script

Tags: google-apps-script

I find this code but it doesn't work like expected.

```
    function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("'Feuille 1'!1:1137");//This line is most likely the culprit
  var to_replace = ".";
  var replace_with = ",";
  replaceInSheet(sheet,range, to_replace, replace_with);
}

function replaceInSheet(sheet, range, to_replace, replace_with) {
  //Confirm
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
  var spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var result = ui.alert(
     "Will update " + to_replace + " to " + replace_with + " ",
     'Are you sure you want to continue?',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  // Process the user's response.
  if (result == ui.Button.YES) {

    // User clicked "Yes".
    spread.toast("Will update " + to_replace + " to " + replace_with + " ", "ALERT");

    var data  = range.getValues();//I think error is occurring here

    var oldValue="";
    var newValue="";
    var cellsChanged = 0;

    for (var row=0; row<data.length; row++) {
      for (var item=0; item<data[row].length; item++) {
        oldValue = data[row][item];
        newValue = data[row][item].replace(to_replace, replace_with);
        if (oldValue!=newValue)
        {
          cellsChanged++;
          data[row][item] = newValue;
        }
      }
    }
    range.setValues(data);
    spread.toast(cellsChanged + " cells changed", "STATUS");
  }
  else {
    // User clicked "No" or X in the title bar.
    spread.toast("No action taken", "ABANDONED");
  }
}
```

I got this error :
TypeError: Impossible d'appeler la méthode "getValues" de undefined. (ligne 25, fichier "Code")

Could you help me I'm a noob
Regards

Answer (score 0):

So apparently this line has a problem:

```
var range = sheet.getRange("'Feuille 1'!1:1137");
```

The range is the problem it should be something like 'Sheet1!A1:A1137'.

So may be this will work: `var range = sheet.getRange("'Feuille 1'!A1:A1137");`

Since I can't see your sheet you will have to determine the appropriate range.

Comment: Hello Cooper thanks for you help,
I tried the 3 possibility but it doesn't work so I decided to change the name of the sheet by "A" and I put this on the code "A!1:1137"
Still it doesn't work.

Comment: See additional comments

Comment: I fixed the first error thanks to you with this "'A'!1:1137"
Now I have another error :
TypeError: Fonction replace introuvable dans l'objet Mon Jul 17 2017 22:27:01 GMT+0200 (CEST). (ligne 34, fichier "Code")

Comment: No one to help me ?

Comment: I think it's in the replace function but the inputs are arguments and I don't know what they are so unless you can shed more light on that then your on your own.